# jQuery Infinite scroll pagination function after 80% Screen height?

Tags: jquery, scroll, pagination, infinite

I have a jQuery infinite scroll pagination. It scroll after 100% screen height (bottom) load added page.
Now i wan to change from 100% screen height to 80% screen height. So what can i do ?

This my site: http://gaixinh.cto.vn/

```
<!-- start infinite scroll function  -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var count = 2;
        var total = <?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                   if (count > total){
                        return false;
                   }else{
                        loadArticle(count);
                   }
                   count++;
                }
        }); 

        function loadArticle(pageNumber){ 

                $('a#inifiniteLoader').show('fast');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    type:'POST',
                    data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop', 
                    success: function(html){
                        $('a#inifiniteLoader').hide('1000');

                        $("#tiles").append(html);    // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
                        $("a[rel='colorbox']").colorbox({
                                transition:'elastic', 
                                opacity:'0.7', 
                                maxHeight:'90%'
                        });
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }

    });


</script>

<!-- end infinite scroll pagination -->
```

Comment: `if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())` change to `if  ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height()*0.8) - $(window).height())`

Comment: Thanks @haxxxton ! i have been changed, but it not work.

Comment: @haxxxton ! when i change from `if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())`  changed to `if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.8)` it work. But is loaded all pages one time

Answer (score 2):

I think the infinite scroll pagination must run after 80 percent of document height (not screen height on your mean).

First set a flag to prevent the function was loop when scrolling

```
var flag = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(flag)
        return; //return if the infinite pagination is calling
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*80/10){
        flag = true;  //set flag
        infiniteLoad();
    }
}); 
function infiniteLoad(){
    //do something
    flag = false; //un set flag
}
```

Comment: Thanks @HDT .. /i have set but it same old .. can't change.

Comment: ! when i change my old jQuery from `if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())`  changed to `if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.8)` it work. But is loaded all pages one time